# Getting the following error in android studio:Program type already present: com.google.api.AuthProto

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

Program type already present:

> com.google.api.AuthProto Message{kind=ERROR, text=Program type already
>   present: com.google.api.AuthProto, sources=[Unknown source file], tool
>   name=Optional.of(D8)}

my dependencies are
**

```
implementation 'com.google.cloud:google-cloud-language:1.31.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:12.0.1'
//compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.4.0'
//compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.3.1'
compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.3.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:17.0.4'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:16.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-invites:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:15.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:16.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-functions:16.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision:16.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-model-interpreter:16.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.0'
compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.22.0'
implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${supportLibVersion}"
implementation "com.android.support:design:${supportLibVersion}"
//compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha8'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
//compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:[4,5)'
//compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25+'
//compile 'com.android.support:design:25+'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25+'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25+'
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
compile 'me.relex:circleindicator:1.2.2@aar'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
compile 'com.github.anastr:speedviewlib:1.1.4'
compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.5'
compile 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v2.1.4'
compile 'me.relex:circleindicator:1.2.1@aar'
compile 'com.roughike:bottom-bar:2.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
compile 'com.github.iffa:wrapping-viewpager:1.0.1'
compile 'com.rm:rmswitch:1.2.2'
compile 'com.github.yalantis:ucrop:2.2.1-native'
compile 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.3.+'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
compile 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client-gson:1.22.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
```

**

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your app gradle inside android

```
 android
 {

 packagingOptions{

   exclude 'com/google/api/AuthPhoto'

    //OR pickFist 'com/google/api/AuthPhoto'

    }
   }
```

Comment: Getting this new error Invoke-customs are only supported starting with Android O (--min-api 26)
Message{kind=ERROR, text=Invoke-customs are only supported starting with Android O (--min-api 26), sources=[Unknown source file], tool name=Optional.of(D8)}

Comment: use android.enableD8=false; inside gradle.properties

Comment: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/protobuf/GeneratedMessageLite$ExtendableMessage$ExtensionWriter;